# Нужно достать определённое поле из базы данных sqlite, что бы измерить количество символов в python django

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, django, sqlite

У меня есть разные поля в базе данных sqlite: title, content, price, published, rubric и ps, мне требуется узнать количество символов в поле ps, что бы потом, передать в html код

Я пробовал вот так, но, это не сработало
(часть кода из html)

```
    {% for bb in bbs %}
        ...
    {% if bb.ps > 0 %}
        <strong>PO SKRIPTU</strong>
        </br><p>{{  bb.ps }}</p>
    {% else %}
        </br>
    {% endif %}
```

Он сразу исполнял код части else, так что, где то, что то, я написал не так, может кто знает?

Вот Часть кода из моделей (models.py) и, контроллера (views.py)

```
def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics}
    return render(request, 'bboard/index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Bb(models.Model):
    ...
    ps = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Po Skriptu')
    ...
```

(с помощью троеточий, указал, что там есть другой код)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно использовать `|length`

`{% if bb.ps|length > 0 %}`

подробней о том, что можно использовать в шаблонах можно почитать https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Но если тебе по сути нужно проверить, что в строке хоть что-то написано, можешь просто писать `{% if bb.ps %}`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!) Вы мне очень сильно помогли). Оказалось, я был гораздо ближе к решению этой проблемы чем я думал, мне просто нужно было немного помощи).